# How to link to external wepage with form HTML?

Tags: html, django, forms

The links contained in the form normally display correctly not in the form but in the form every time I click the button I get a forbidden access error. Is the HTML correct? Is there a way around this?

```
{% for v in owner_obj %}
    <div class="container">
    <form action="{{ v.Link }}" method="POST" type="submit">
        <button style="border: none;">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="tshirt_id" value="{{ v.id }}" />
    <a href="{{ v.Link }}" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img src="{{ v.Images }}" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
        </button>

    </form>

    <figcaption>  {{ v.Titles }} </figcaption>
    <figcaption> <b>{{ v.Prices }}</b></figcaption>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Added views.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        T_shirt.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('tshirt_id')).update(views=F('views') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that if the external website has the validation of csrf_token, because is insecure if anyone is able to do a post to your url from outsite of your website. The only way to do that is if the external website disable the csrf_token validation.

With ajax should be something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".counter-button").on("click", function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    var url = $(this).attr("href");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ request.path }}",
                        data: {
                            'tshirt_id': data_id
                        },
                        success: function () {
                      window.location.replace(url);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for v in owner_obj %}
            <div class="container">
                <a href="{{ v.Link }}" class="counter-button" data-id="{{ v.id }}">
                    <img src="{{ v.Images }}" width="150" height="150">
                </a>
                <figcaption>  {{ v.Titles }} </figcaption>
                <figcaption> <b>{{ v.Prices }}</b></figcaption>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

You have to include Jquery before the javascript script.

And then in the added views.py you should do something like this:

```
import json

from django.http import JsonResponse


def added(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('UTF-8'))
        T_shirt.objects.filter(
            id=post_data.get('tshirt_id')
        ).update(views=F('views') + 1)
        return JsonResponse({"message": "success"})
```

Comment: Is there another way to link to an external webpage without using a form? The form is only used to increment a counter every time a user clicks on it. The external link works if there is no form

Comment: Yes, an ajax post with jquery for example

Comment: Do you know how to replace the above code with ajax?

Comment: Thank you for submitting your answer. I have added views.py above. The "views" column  i have in my DB does not increment by 1 when the link is clicked. Do you know why that is? I think it has something to do with the if request.method == 'POST':. Is there something like this for ajax

Comment: oh these external websites are yours? you have two options, don't use jquery and add this decorator to your view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt or use jquery and get the data from `request.body`

Comment: These external websites are not mine. some are forbidden and some work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231998/discussion-between-diego-puente-and-jeffgrills).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this doesent work but you might have to put

```
{{ v.Link }}
```